# iOS 14.2 directs app audio output to ear speaker instead of bottom speaker

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, speaker, speakerphone

An app that I built has always output its audio through the bottom speaker (speakerphone), but it now outputs to the front (ear) speaker. I have not changed the app, so I assume the cause must be iOS 14.2, which I recently installed.

The app uses `AVAudioSession`, setting `AVAudioSession.Category` to `.playAndRecord` because it performs both audio recording and speech synthesis.

Any idea what 14.2 may have changed to cause this… and how I can specify that the output go to the bottom speaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it was simply a matter of adding `.defaultToSpeaker` during setup:

`try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: .defaultToSpeaker)`

I'm not sure why the option was only necessary beginning with iOS 14.2, but it solves the problem.

Comment: Any more recent info? We don't want to default to the speaker, but when we *are* using the speaker we'd like it to also use the bottom speaker and not just the earpiece!

Comment: @Meekohi using the speaker means never using the earpiece. But this won't affect things if you're using a bluetooth device, etc. So I think this is what you want.

Comment: I haven't figured out any way to get the behavior you're describing -- if I use `defaultToSpeaker` then the output *always* goes to the speaker, even when Bluetooth headsets are connected.

Comment: @Meekohi to be honest I've only tested it with plug-in headphones rather than bluetooth - but that does override the speaker fine. In the Apple docs it says: "The use case is to route audio to the speaker instead of the receiver in cases where the audio would normally go to the receiver." — which sounds to me like exactly what you are seeking. I'm sorry it's not working for you. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616462-defaulttospeaker